# Make "a" item of div not be the full width of div

Tags: html, css, formatting

I want to create a titlebar with just the title of the page. I want the "a" item not to be the full width of the div (the whole webpage width), but only the width of the text.
Here is a photo of how it looks now. Image of problem:
[image: Image of problem]
How can I do that?
Should I use 2 divs?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body margin = "0">
    <div id='titlebar'>
        <a href='/'>Dimitrie David</a>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

CSS:

```
#titlebar {
    background: #333333;
}
#titlebar a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 25px 15px 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have "display: block;" in the css for the a element? (twice even). If you remove that the a element will naturally only be the width of it's content/text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: block` from `#titlebar a`. By default an `a` tag in an inline element and should only be as wide as its content. Block elements have `100%` width by default.

Comment: It works, but now my top and bottom paddings are not working.

Comment: @DavidDimitrie Move the padding into the #titlebar { ... } section and then the div will have the padding around the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
#titlebar {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Compared to display: block, the major difference is that display: inline-block does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit next to other elements. From [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a relative width, e.g. width: 20% (play around with exact numbers). Elements with relative width (or height) will be that percentage of width/height of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block instead of display:block

```
    #titlebar a{
        display: inline-block;
    }
```